# Use Row number from Cells.Find in new Range/Rows definition

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, range

I hope In some help to debug this simple code.

I am trying to cut and paste a Range of rows identified by specific cell  value, for every sheet in the workbook

My problem is that When I define the Range to be cut I receive the 1004 error.

Below my code:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count


     ' Define Range Boundaries and insert Location
    Dim Lstress As String
       Lstress = (Cells.Find(What:="Long Shear (N)", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row) - 1
       MsgBox "Last Row:" & Lstress
    Dim Disp As String
       Disp = Cells.Find(What:="Displacement X(m)", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
       MsgBox "Last Row:" & Disp
    Dim Rigging As String
       Rigging = (Cells.Find(What:="Standing Rigging", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row) - 1
       MsgBox "Last Row:" & Rigging
    Dim Cutrange As String
       Let Cutrange = "A" & Disp & ":" & "D" & Lstress

      'Cut and Paste Action
       Range("CutRange").Cut
       Rows("Rigging").Insert Shift:=xlDown

      ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
      ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
       MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

     Next I

  End Sub
```

Same error if I try to use instead of Range, Rows

`Rows("Disp:Lstress").Cut`

I think the issue is related to the output of Cells.Find.Row. 
I mean the numerical value in the mesgBox is correct but probably the format is not valid to be used in Range/Rows.

Thank you for your Help 
Edoardo

Comment: Remove the inverted commas from `Range("CutRange").cut.` CutRange is a string variable, so does not need quotes! Repeat for "Rigging"

Comment: Also, there's no need to `Dim` the variables on each loop. Move these so that they are below `Dim I as Integer`

Comment: Thank you so much for your Help @MiguelH , also for aswering to this trivial issue.